# C# ControlCollection Extension GetAllTextboxes

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, controlcollection

How could I get only the texboxes in a ControlCollection ?

I try :

```
public static IEnumerable<TextBox> TextBoxes(this ControlCollection controlCollection)
{
    return (IEnumerable<TextBox>)controlCollection.Cast<Control>().Where(c => c is TextBox);
}
```

But I got the following error : 
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Web.UI.Control]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox]'.

I Use Asp.Net 3.5 with C#

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't actually need a new extension method - there's already one for you that will get this:

```
controlCollection.OfType<TextBox>();
```

The [OfType method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) returns a sequence (`IEnumerable<T>`) subset of the sequence provided. If the type isn't convertible, it's left out. Unlike most of the LINQ extension methods, `OfType` is available on sequences that aren't strongly-typed:

> This method is one of the few standard query operator methods that can be applied to a collection that has a non-parameterized type, such as an ArrayList. This is because OfType<(Of <(TResult>)>) extends the type IEnumerable.

Or if you do want to wrap it in an extension method, it's of course quite simple:

```
public static IEnumerable<TextBox> TextBoxes(this ControlCollection controls)
{
    return controls.OfType<TextBox>();
}
```

Comment: That's actually better of what I was needed!

Answer (score 1):

You want OfType():

```
public static IEnumerable<TextBox> TextBoxes(this ControlCollection controlCollection)
{
    return controlCollection.OfType<TextBox>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive extension method to get the `Control` objects that descend from the specified type, including those that are nested in the control hierarchy.

```
public static class ControlCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OfTypeRecursive<T>(this ControlCollection controls) where T : Control
    {
        foreach (Control c in controls)
        {
            T ct = c as T;

            if (ct != null)
                yield return ct;

            foreach (T cc in OfTypeRecursive<T>(c.Controls))
                yield return cc;
        }
    }
}
```

(For Windows Forms instead of ASP.NET, substitute `Control.ControlCollection` for `ControlCollection`.)

Comment: Or you could use OfType() with the non-recursive GetDescendantControls() method defined here: http://solutionizing.net/2009/06/23/refactoring-with-linq-iterators-finddescendantcontrol-and-getdescendantcontrols/

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (TextBox tBox in controls)
{

}
```

> Example:

```
public static void HideControls<T>(Form pForm)
{
    foreach (T cont in pForm.Controls)
    {
        cont.Visible = false;
    }
}

HideControls<TextBox>(this);
HideControls<CheckedListBox>(this);
```